# How to retain timezone when formatting a date in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date like `2015-10-24T17:12-05:00` and I'm using moment.js to format it like this:

```
moment('2015-10-24T17:12-05:00').format('h:mm A');
```

Instead of showing the time in the timezone specified in the string, moment.js seems to be converting it to the timezone of my computer. How can I preserve the timezone when I am formatting?

Comment: There may be something relevant in their Timezone library but I didn't see something that just did what you wanted. http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: @MrHen I think it's just a case of doing `moment(...).tz(x).format(...)` where `x` is the timezone to display the time in.  Been a while since I looked at it though.

Comment: @JamesThorpe You're kinda right but the issue is, tz() expects a string like "America/Los_Angeles" and I don't have that. I only have the offset in the string. I think I have to write my own lookup table and have it map to a name like "America/Los_Angeles'.

Comment: Right.  May be worth looking at the way it holds the built in timezones - it must know what the offsets are for them, perhaps there's a way to reverse lookup an existing one from the table

Answer (score 3):

```js
var estTime = '2019-09-01T14:30:00-04:00';
var istTime = "2019-10-01T23:20:00+05:30";
console.log(estTime , "  ", moment(estTime).format("hh:mm") ," ", moment.parseZone(estTime).format("hh:mm"));
console.log(istTime, "  ", moment(istTime).format("hh:mm"), " ", moment.parseZone(istTime).format("hh:mm"));
```

Moment's string parsing functions like `moment(string)` and `moment.utc(string)` accept offset information if provided, but convert the resulting Moment object to local or UTC time. In contrast, `moment.parseZone()` parses the string but keeps the resulting Moment object in a fixed-offset timezone with the provided offset in the string.

[parseZone](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/)

Output:

> 2019-09-01T14:30:00-04:00    02:30   02:30
>
> 2019-10-01T23:20:00+05:30    01:50   11:20

Comment: Use "HH" instead of "hh" to see in 24 hours clock